# get minimum & maximum value of dense matrix elements

Tags: c#, numeric, math.net, mathnet-numerics

Using `MathNet.numerics` for C# , I have created dense matrix of doubles.

I wish to find the minimum & maximum element-value of a matrix.

Is there an accessor to get the maximum/minimum value of the dense matrix elements?

Actually I do this

```
var minValue = MyDenseMatrix.Values.Min();
var minValue = MyDenseMatrix.Values.Max();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none. Vectors do have Minimum/Maximum methods, so I've just opened ticket [#160](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/160) to add the symmetric functionality to matrices as well.

The way you do it in the example code is actually reasonable and fast, but will work only with dense matrices. Otherwise you can use the `Enumerate()` or for sparse also `EnumerateNonZero()` methods to get a normal enumerable you can use with LINQ or our statistics classes.